# How to find the regex pattern to find there's code and replace it with blank

Tags: javascript, regex, pdf

I have a strings where there's possible code and I want to replace it with blank

Example -

Input = `9eac83a4-80f4-4a2e-b0fe-7a4a9329ff62Manual Handling.pdf`

Output I want = `Manual Handling.pdf`

Input = `14a19827-8f33-4666-a3cc-ea257875f1f7Fire&Evac.pdf`

OutPut I want = `Fire&Evac.pdf`

Input = `67a89d74-57a9-43cc-9576-001f9315d292BLS-1.pdf`

OutPut I want = `BLS-1.pdf`

Input = `7622a004-43b8-4357-8c95-c8a269e6ef7827276e859ef10d-Mango Super.pdf`

Output I want = `Mango Super.pdf`

Input = `d5b0f745aa80d9- Calc.png`

Output I want = `Calc.png`

Input = `d5b0f745aa80d9980d090- Covid-19-Test.png`

Output I want = `Covid-19-Test.png`

Input = `d5b0f745aa80d9980d090-2a004-43b8-4357-8 Covid-19 Vacc.png`

Output I want = `Covid-19 Vacc.png`

How can I do this?

I tried this regex but not working for all of those(above) cases

```
var str = "9eac83a4-80f4-4a2e-b0fe-7a4a9329ff62Manual Handling.pdf";
var cleanStr = str.replace(/[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-4[a-f0-9]{3}-[89aAbB][a-f0-9]{3}-[a-f0-9]{12}/g, "");
```

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your regex is much too strict to match on `d5b0f745aa80d9- Calc.png`. Is there a reason why you're not loosening the regex to `/[a-f\d-]{14,} */`? Would this cause false positives for other strings you don't want to match? A bit more context might help here. Thanks.

Comment: I am also filtering the UUIDs @ggorlen

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```regex
.*?(?=[A-Z].*$)
```

- `.*?` capture everything loosely
- `(?=[A-Z].*$)` - check that ahead of me should be a capital letter followed by anything; do not capture this

```js
const data = `9eac83a4-80f4-4a2e-b0fe-7a4a9329ff62Manual Handling.pdf
14a19827-8f33-4666-a3cc-ea257875f1f7Fire&Evac.pdf
67a89d74-57a9-43cc-9576-001f9315d292BLS-1.pdf
7622a004-43b8-4357-8c95-c8a269e6ef7827276e859ef10d-Mango Super.pdf
d5b0f745aa80d9- Calc.png
d5b0f745aa80d9980d090- Covid-19-Test.png
d5b0f745aa80d9980d090-2a004-43b8-4357-8 Covid-19 Vacc.png`;

const pattern = /.*?(?=[A-Z].*$)/;
data.split(/\n/).forEach(e => console.log(e.replace(pattern, "")));
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple pattern `/[a-f\d-]{14,} */` works for all of your cases:

```js
const data = `9eac83a4-80f4-4a2e-b0fe-7a4a9329ff62Manual Handling.pdf
14a19827-8f33-4666-a3cc-ea257875f1f7Fire&Evac.pdf
67a89d74-57a9-43cc-9576-001f9315d292BLS-1.pdf
7622a004-43b8-4357-8c95-c8a269e6ef7827276e859ef10d-Mango Super.pdf
d5b0f745aa80d9- Calc.png
d5b0f745aa80d9980d090- Covid-19-Test.png
d5b0f745aa80d9980d090-2a004-43b8-4357-8 Covid-19 Vacc.png`;

const pattern = /[a-f\d-]{14,} */;
data.split(/\n/).forEach(e => console.log(e.replace(pattern, "")));
```

If this is giving false positives on other strings, a clearer specification for the prefix id format(s) seems necessary.